# How can i update my firebase database fields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good Day.
I have tried my level best but failed to update the data whenever i enter new "Name","Age" or anything the data entered before is wiped.I want to use push or something else to update the data.But still failing to do that.

```
nameRef.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String ho = name.getText().toString();

                nameRef.setValue(ho);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        genderRef.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String ho = gender.getText().toString();
                genderRef.setValue(ho);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        ageRef.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           `enter code here`     String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String ho = age.getText().toString();
                ageRef.setValue(ho);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        EmailRef.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String ho = email.getText().toString();
                EmailRef.setValue(ho);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON tree like this:

```
->users
    ->uid
        ->name
        ->age
        ->gender
        ->email
```

Then to update the values in the database you should do something like this:

```
DatabaseReference mFirebaseDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

//use a POJO and make sure to have a default empty constructor in that class definition
User user = new User(name, age, gender, email)
mFirebaseDBRef.child("users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
```

And that should update your database! If something is not clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: What is User?is that a class?

Comment: Is there a way i can use push()? @Ghost_Stark

Comment: Yes that is a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) class you create to store the data fields for each user or whatever object you are storing data on.

Comment: I believe `push()` creates a new item in your database, but since you want to update the fields you would have to use `setValue()`. This page gives more info on this exact question: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

Comment: But i guess even adding a new item would serve the purpose.Can you tell me how can i incorporate push() @Ghost_Stark

Comment: Still can't figure out! @Ghost_Stark